# Intermittent Kerberos failures: GSSAPI authentication initialization failed

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, kerberos, gssapi

When using *MIT Kerberos Ticket Manager* with *PuTTY* 0.65 and *WinSCP* 5.9.3, I am sometimes unable to get a connnection to the server I am logging into. PuTTY will respond with either `No supported authentication methods available (server sent: )` or `No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)`

It seems to happen most often if I try to connect to the server before remembering to obtain a ticket first. After getting a ticket, I will keep getting the same error every time I try. It sometimes resolves itself after about an hour.

The connection to both the authentication server and the server I'm trying to connect to operates over a VPN.

I don't get any issues when using *Cygwin* + `kinit`.

Here's my log:

```
. 2017-01-28 14:04:38.979 Server offered these authentication methods: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
. 2017-01-28 14:04:38.980 Using SSPI from SECUR32.DLL
. 2017-01-28 14:04:38.980 Attempting GSSAPI authentication
. 2017-01-28 14:04:39.008 GSSAPI authentication initialisation failed
. 2017-01-28 14:04:39.008 No authority could be contacted for authentication.The domain name of the authenticating party could be wrong, the domain could be unreachable, or there might have been a trust relationship failure.
. 2017-01-28 14:04:39.008 Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: )
* 2017-01-28 14:04:39.060 (EFatal) Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your DNS settings when the problem is reproduced runing  `ipconfig /all`. Among DNS servers should not be anyone who does not know about the domain to which your server.

You can check this by run for each DNS server ip:

```
nslookup -type=srv _kerberos._tcp.<your server REALM> <DNS server ip>
```

If the query does not return any entries for some servers - try to remove this server from your settings, clean DNS cache (`ipconfig /flushdns`) and retry connection.

> I don't get any issues when using Cygwin + kinit.

I believe that *Cygwin* uses own DNS configuration from `/etc/resole.conf` so to him the problem does not play.

Comment: Excellent answer, especially with the nslookup command debugging hint. It did turn out to be a DNS issue. My ISP's DNS is unreachable through the VPN so unless I contact the Kerberos realm before tunnel my connection, the lookup will time out. Changing my DNS servers to Google's public DNS works well.